Create a ValidationPipe Middleware in nestjs
i have this ValidatorPipe that should be the same as ValidationPipe in my nestjs server:
@Injectable()
export class ValidatorPipe extends ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  constructor(private defaultValidatorOptions?: ValidationPipeOptions) {
    super(defaultValidatorOptions)
  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const extraValidatorOptions = this.getExtraValidatorOptions(value, metadata)
    this.validatorOptions = { ...this.defaultValidatorOptions, ...extraValidatorOptions }

    // Continue with the standard validation afterwards
    return super.transform(value, metadata)
  }

  protected getExtraValidatorOptions(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): ValidationPipeOptions {
    // code that should check for extra validation options...
  }
}

I'm looking for a way to get from the request some metadata, that i can use to choose the right validation options for the call that entered the server.
i have try to send metadata.data for the request, but, i cant get anything... it always was undefined..
